# Usando multiplos group by e somas no google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Boa noite pessoal. Estou com uma dúvida na melhor forma de montar um resultado que some e agrupe determinas células e uma aba do google sheets. Para ficar mais claro, vamos ao exemplo do código:
Tenho 4 Abas em minha planilha:

```
Sheets-Final
Sheets-A
Sheets-B
Sheets-C
```

As abas **Sheets-B** e **Sheets-C** contém os seguintes valores:

```
Sheets-B
Nome     Campanha     Total   Tipo
Nome A   Campanha A   8       Tipo 1
Nome B   Campanha B   4       Tipo 1
Nome C   Campanha C   3       Tipo 1

Sheets-C
Nome     Campanha     Total   Tipo
Nome A   Campanha A   5       Tipo 2
Nome B   Campanha B   3       Tipo 2
Nome C   Campanha C   3       Tipo 2
```

Na **Sheets-A** eu utilizado para agrupar todos os resultados das **Sheets-B** e **Sheets-C**. **Sheets-B e C** são utilizadas com uma automação que as alimenta, por isso estão separados. Para fazer esse agrupamento eu utilizo a seguinte query:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_TEXT({Sheets-B!A:D;Sheets-C!A:D});"SELECT * WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL";1))
```

Agregando os resultado a **Sheets-A** fica da seguinte maneira:

```
Sheets-A
Nome     Campanha     Total   Tipo
Nome A   Campanha A   8       Tipo 1
Nome B   Campanha B   4       Tipo 1
Nome C   Campanha C   3       Tipo 1
Nome A   Campanha A   5       Tipo 2
Nome B   Campanha B   3       Tipo 2
Nome C   Campanha C   3       Tipo 2
```

O que eu preciso agora é que o meu resultado final eu consiga agrupar e somar os totais ficando a sheets da seguinte maneira:

```
Nome     Campanha     Tipo 1 Total    Tipo 2 Total
Nome A   Campanha A   8               5
Nome B   Campanha B   4               3
Nome C   Campanha C   3               3
```

fazendo com que as somas fiquem em colunas e não mais em linhas. Esse exemplo me ajudará a ter um norte de como fazer. Teste fazendo a seguinte query no sheets mas não rolou:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({Sheets-A!A:D};"SELECT Col1, Col2, sum(Col3), Col4 where Col1 is not null group by Col1, Col2";1))
```

Talvez uma das maiores dificuldades e transformar os totais em colunas, como no resultado esperado.

Answer (score -1):

Umas das formas de você transformar esses totais em colunas é fazer duas query e em seguidas juntá-las - transformando o resultado em nova matriz

Com base nas amostras do seu post, você pode tentar a seguinte formula:

```
={QUERY({A1:D};"select Col1, Col2, SUM(Col3) where Col4 = 'Tipo 1' AND Col1 IS NOT NULL GROUP BY Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 label SUM(Col3) 'Tipo 1 Total'";1)\QUERY({A1:D};"select SUM(Col3) where Col4 = 'Tipo 2' AND Col1 IS NOT NULL GROUP BY Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 label SUM(Col3) 'Tipo 2 Total'";1)}
```

O link com a imagem mostra o resultado final

[Resultado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKRa6.png)